# Cast pointer of the base class to pointer of the inherited class with template

Tags: c++

My code looks something like this:

```
class A {
    ...
};

template<typename T>
class B: public A {
    ...
};

A* pointerA = new B<X>(...);
```

But now I want to cast another pointerB to pointerA:

```
B<...>* pointerB = (B<...>*)pointerA;
```

How do I know what to insert into <...> or how I should do this correctly?

Comment: You should use dynamic_cast, unless you are absolutely certain the type is correct.

Comment: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the cast with `dynamic_cast`. If you `dynamic_cast` to a *pointer type* and it fails, you get a null pointer back. If you `dynamic_cast` to a *reference type* and it fails, you'll get an exception.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A {};

int main() {
    A* pointerA = new B<int>;
    
    auto pointerB = dynamic_cast<B<double>*>(pointerA);
    if(pointerB) {
        std::cout << "cast succeeded\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "cast failed\n";      // will print "cast failed"
    }

    delete pointerA;
}
```

---

If you have many of them stored in a `vector` you need to test all possible types to be able to cast back to the original type.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A {};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vec;
    
    vec.emplace_back(new B<int>);
    vec.emplace_back(new B<std::string>);

    for(auto& ptr : vec) {
        if(auto b = dynamic_cast<B<int>*>(ptr.get())) {
            std::cout << "B<int>\n";
        } else if(auto b = dynamic_cast<B<std::string>*>(ptr.get())) {
            std::cout << "B<std::string>\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Oh, unknown derived type stored ...\n";
        }
    }    
}
```

It's preferable to add `virtual` methods to the base class and implement them in the derived classes to not have to do this cast at all though.

Comment: @RyukGodOfTheDeathhh You're welcome. Ok, go ahead an update the question :-)

Comment: Thanks for the code example! However, I realized that I did not quite accurately described my problem.
More detailed example:
`vector<A*> vec;
vec.push_back(new B<int>(...));
vec.push_back(new B<string(...));
vec.push_back(new C(...));`
I filled vec with some intances of class B (typename T can be int, double, string or char) or with some intstances with class C(it's not templated class).
Then I want to iterate through each element of vec A and cast pointer of A to pointer of B, but I don't know the typename

I'm so sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @RyukGodOfTheDeathhh Ok, that's nothing different. You'll just have to try them all. I added that to the answer.

Comment: Try them all. Hmmeh! There is no try.

Comment: @user4581301 Just do? :-)

Comment: Correct, Nike was. Yes. Just do it, you must.

Comment: @user4581301 :-) I'm trying, I'm trying.